browser-solidity-compiler Uncaught Error: Function not implemented
Trying to compile smart contracts in the browser so people can deploy a token straight from my website.
Here is the code:
    const version = "soljson-v0.8.23+commit.f704f362.js";

    setCompiling(true);

    try {
      generateTokenContract(
        data.token_name,
        data.token_symbol,
        data.token_decimals,
        data.token_supply
      );

      let compiled;

      try {
        compiled = (await solidityCompiler({
          version: `https://binaries.soliditylang.org/bin/${version}`,
          contractBody: generateTokenContract(
            data.token_name,
            data.token_symbol,
            data.token_decimals,
            data.token_supply
          ),
          options: {
            optimizer: {
              enabled: true,
              runs: 200,
            },
          },
        })) as CompiledContract;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
      }


However I get following error:



It says node_modules@agnostico\browser-solidity-compiler\dist\browser.solidity.worker.js (28:0) @ eval
⨯ ReferenceError: window is not defined
IN console
